# How to display yesterdays date in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-expression

In one of the column name, I need to display yesterday's date like - `September 4,2014`

I used `DateAdd("d",-1,Today())` function to display,but it is displaying like - `9/4/2014 12:00:00 AM`.

How can i get the above format like - `monthname,dd,YYYY` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use .. `=format(dateadd("d", -1, today()), "MMMM dd,yyyy")`

Comment: IS there any way ,i can make Month name Caps in the above expression?

Comment: use UCase function .. `=UCase(format(dateadd("d", -1, today()), "MMMM,dd,yyyy"))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want add dynamic date or yesterday date in email body using ssrs tool SQL Server 2017, please fellow these steps:

Step 1>

[image]

Upload rdl file .

Step 2> Right click on file

[image]

Then click manage

[image]

Step 3> In Left menu click Subscription

[image]

Step 4> Click New Subscription

[image]

You will see this window

[image]

Then choose data-driven subscription

[image]

Then click edit dataset

[image]

Then you will get below window

[image]

From this select custom source you will get below window

[image]

after filling all type query like you want yesterday date then type below query:

[image]

Then click Validate Query AND APPLY

IN SUBJECT TAKE VALUE FROM DATABASE AND SEND MAIL